# Touchpad randomly stops working (16.04.3)

Tags: mouse, touchpad, cursor

All i use my laptop for is chrome, discord and rarely some other basic apps such as runescape, emulators, etc. Anyway, after a while, and a lot on runescape, the cursor will stop moving, and i wont have any control over it. It will get stuck in 1 place. I will be able to click, where its stuck, but not move it. What is the issue?

Just to add on, the keyboard still work. If i plug in a usb mouse, the cursor starts moving again. So its a problem with the touchpad, but it doesnt happen on windows so it isnt a hardware problem.

Comment: What's your distro? Interface installed?

Comment: "What's your distro? Interface installed?" Sorry i dont understand this

Comment: Is it ubuntu with unity? Kubuntu? Xubuntu? .. etc

Comment: ubuntu with unity, also i made a slight edit in my original point just to add on.

Comment: Could be a hardware issue, if it was dropped or the cables moved, I had the same issue a while back and the solution was replacing the touchpad cable.

Comment: Na defo not, it happens only on ubuntu