# Touchpad randomly stops responding

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS on my Acer Aspire laptop, and I have encountered a strange problem with my mousepad.

When using the computer, the touchpad will randomly stop working (I have not been able to figure out what triggers it). The cursor will no longer respond to movement on the touchpad, however clicks still work (in the spot where the cursor is stuck). When I try to move the cursor, it repeatedly click (such as selecting a body of text).

I have tried plugging in an external mouse, and that works no problem. I also have Windows in a separate partition on the same computer, and there has never been any problem with the touchpad, so I am fairly certain it is a software issue.

I have also looked at the "xinput" list of devices, and both the touchpad, mouse, and external mouse show up:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0501:00 04F3:3019 Mouse               id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse          id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse Consumer Control id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0501:00 04F3:3019 Touchpad            id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

(the MOSART lines correspond to the external bluetooth mouse).

When I disable number 12, the clicking action on the mouse is disables (does not respond at all). When I disable 13, there is no change.

The only way I have found to recover use of my mouse is to reboot the PC, but after a while (sometimes several horus, sometimes mere minutes) the problem returns and I have no mousepad, and it is interfering with my work :(

I have found a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002391/touchpad-randomly-stops-working-16-04-3), where there seems to be the same problem, but no answer was given and the thread has been inactive for a couple years.

Edit: It may seem dumb but yes, I have tried the mouse disable key ;)

Comment: Not a solution here, but I was experiencing the exact same issue with Apple Magic Trackpad - external. Moving stopped sporadically, clicking still worked. In my case this was happening when trackpad was connected to the hub that was connected to the monitor's hub. I tried to connect trackpad directly into usb port on a pc and it has been working flawlessly since then. Again, not an answer, but one can try and see what other usb devices are connected and trying without them. In my case looks that some contention and indirection was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem, although on Ubuntu 18.04.1.  A temporary, but annoying, workaround I've found is to keep reactivating the touchpad with the F7 key:  that is, you press the (Fn, F7) once and then again after which the touchpad and the mousepointer seem to work.

Will be glad to know of a more permanent fix.

Comment: For my PC, the Fn-F7 combo corresponds to the mouse disable key, and has no effect on this particular issue. I'm glad it works for you though haha